# responsive navbar with bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

When viewed on mobile devices I would like my navbar not to collapse, but stay as in the original desktop website. I have achieved this by overwriting the CSS in a media screen (code below). I would like, however, the navbar to stretch across the whole width, and this I cannot achieve.

I tried changing background-color of navbar-default to black, but it adds some margin which I can't seem to remove.

```css
@media screen 
  and (min-width: 320px)
  and (max-width: 767px)
  and (orientation: landscape) {
    body{
      margin: 0 auto;
      background-image:  url(../images/background_vm.jpg);
      /*background-repeat:no-repeat;*/
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-size:100% auto;
      font-family: 'Tinos', 'Times New Roman';
      font-size: 22px;
      margin-top: 0px;
    }
    .head-bg{
      width: 100%;
      height: 50px;
      background: url(../images/nadpis2_bg.jpg);
      background-size:100% 100%;
      background-attachment: fixed;
    }
    .flags{
      margin-top: -25px;
      padding-right: 35px;
    }
    .flags img{
      width: 35%;
    }
    .container{
      max-width: 760px;
    }
    .content{
      padding: 15px;
    }
    .height{
      height: 50px;
      background-color: transparent;
    }
    /* Always float the navbar header */
    .navbar-header {
      float: left;
    }
    /* Undo the collapsing navbar */
    .navbar-collapse {
      display: block !important;
      height: auto !important;
      padding-bottom: 0;
      overflow: visible !important;
      visibility: visible !important;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
      display: none;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
      border-top: 0;
    }
    /* Always apply the floated nav */
    .navbar-nav {
      background-color: #000;
      float: none;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .navbar-nav > li {
      float: left;
    }
    .navbar-default {
      background-color: transparent;
      border-color: transparent;
      border-top-color: white;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
      padding-left: 20px;
      padding-right: 20px;
      padding-top: 3px;
      padding-bottom: 3px;
      color: white;
      font-size: 12px;
    }
    /* Redeclare since we override the float above */
    .navbar-nav.navbar-right {
      float: right;
    }
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="head-bg">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="pull-right flags hidden-xs">
      <a><img src="/images/bg_ico.png" alt="BG"></a>
      <a href=<!--#echo var="MENU_NAME"-->><img src="/images/eng_ico.png" alt="EN"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="height"></div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="row collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav np">
        <li class="nol"><a href="/bg/home">ЗА НАС</a></li>
        <li><a href="/bg/studio">СТУДИО</a></li>
        <li><a href="/bg/gallery">ГАЛЕРИЯ</a></li>
        <li><a href="/bg/news">НОВИНИ</a></li>
        <li><a href="/bg/shop">Е-МАГАЗИН</a></li>
        <li class="nor"><a href="/bg/contact">КОНТАКТИ</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="pull-right flags visible-xs">
    <a><img src="/images/bg_ico.png"  alt="BG"></a>
    <a href=<!--#echo var="MENU_NAME"-->><img src="/images/eng_ico.png"  alt="EN"></a>
</div>
```

**Here is a photo of what it looks like now:**

[image]

**And here is a photo of what I would like it to be:**

[image]

Comment: Please create a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) using the code and any other relevant stylesheets etc. that you have, so we can see the issue in action.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9sodzebh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to apply style to the ul inside the navbar-collapse div. Here is the css.

```
.navbar-collapse > ul {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
}
```

Here is the fixed example:

```css
@media screen 
  and (min-width: 320px)
  and (max-width: 767px)
  and (orientation: landscape) {
    body{
      margin: 0 auto;
      background-image:  url(../images/background_vm.jpg);
      /*background-repeat:no-repeat;*/
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-size:100% auto;
      font-family: 'Tinos', 'Times New Roman';
      font-size: 22px;
      margin-top: 0px;
    }
    .head-bg{
      width: 100%;
      height: 50px;
      background: url(../images/nadpis2_bg.jpg);
      background-size:100% 100%;
      background-attachment: fixed;
    }
    .flags{
      margin-top: -25px;
      padding-right: 35px;
    }
    .flags img{
      width: 35%;
    }
    .container{
      max-width: 760px;
    }
    .content{
      padding: 15px;
    }
    .height{
      height: 50px;
      background-color: transparent;
    }
    /* Always float the navbar header */
    .navbar-header {
      float: left;
    }
    /* Undo the collapsing navbar */
    .navbar-collapse {
      display: block !important;
      height: auto !important;
      padding-bottom: 0;
      overflow: visible !important;
      visibility: visible !important;
    }
    .navbar-collapse > ul {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto !important;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
      display: none;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
      border-top: 0;
    }
    /* Always apply the floated nav */
    .navbar-nav {
      background-color: #000;
      float: none;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .navbar-nav > li {
      float: left;
    }
    .navbar-default {
      background-color: transparent;
      border-color: transparent;
      border-top-color: white;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
      padding-left: 20px;
      padding-right: 20px;
      padding-top: 3px;
      padding-bottom: 3px;
      color: white;
      font-size: 12px;
    }
    /* Redeclare since we override the float above */
    .navbar-nav.navbar-right {
      float: right;
    }
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="head-bg">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="pull-right flags hidden-xs">
      <a><img src="/images/bg_ico.png" alt="BG"></a>
      <a href=<!--#echo var="MENU_NAME"-->><img src="/images/eng_ico.png" alt="EN"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="height"></div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="row collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav np">
        <li class="nol"><a href="/bg/home">ЗА НАС</a></li>
        <li><a href="/bg/studio">СТУДИО</a></li>
        <li><a href="/bg/gallery">ГАЛЕРИЯ</a></li>
        <li><a href="/bg/news">НОВИНИ</a></li>
        <li><a href="/bg/shop">Е-МАГАЗИН</a></li>
        <li class="nor"><a href="/bg/contact">КОНТАКТИ</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="pull-right flags visible-xs">
    <a><img src="/images/bg_ico.png"  alt="BG"></a>
    <a href=<!--#echo var="MENU_NAME"-->><img src="/images/eng_ico.png"  alt="EN"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Applying the style to the ul inside the navbar-collapse div did the job, but now it floats to the left side rather than center.

Comment: On the code snippet running here there is no left float. Please open a new question or update this one with a new code snippet/jsFiddle, since my code snippet doesn't have a float to the left.

Comment: Maybe I am not explaining it correctly, sorry. The whole menu stays at the left side when you resize the screen width (also your snippet above). In the original code the navigation stays in the center of the page

Comment: this solution worked as I wanted with the extra lines of code:

    .navbar-nav>li {
 display: inline-block;
 float:none;
    }